# C# connecting to mySql with hebrew encoding throws exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to mySql DB. this DB should support hebrew.
In my connection string I added the keyword: charSet = UTF8. When trying to open the connection I get the following exception:
Keyword not supported: 'charset'. 
the exception occures at this line: `[ myDataCon = new DataContext(GetConnectionString());]`

My code:

```
[ 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConstructionProjectBackgroundService
{
    class DBHandler
    {
        static DBHandler dbHandler;
        DataContext myDataCon;
        public MySqlConnection DataConnection { get; set; }
        public DataContext Dc
        {
            get { return myDataCon; }
        }

        private string GetConnectionString()
        {

            string connString = "User = root; Server = localhost; Database = construction_project; charset = UTF8;";        //connString for MySQLPHPAdmin
            return connString;
        }

        private DBHandler()
        {
            DataConnection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            myDataCon = new DataContext(GetConnectionString());
        }

        public static DBHandler GetInstance()
        {
            if (dbHandler == null)
            {
                dbHandler = new DBHandler();
            }
            return dbHandler;
        }

        public ArrayList execQuery(string query)
        {

            MySqlCommand command = DBHandler.GetInstance().DataConnection.CreateCommand();

            try
            {
                DBHandler.GetInstance().DataConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }

            command.CommandText = query;
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            ArrayList Filters = new ArrayList();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string[] temp = new string[reader.FieldCount + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = reader[i].ToString();
                }
                Filters.Add(temp);
            }
            DBHandler.GetInstance().DataConnection.Close();

            return Filters;
        }
    }
}
]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: try using 'utf8' instead of 'UTF8'.  The docs seem to suggest that case matters here.

Comment: No... I still get the exception

Comment: Try writing it exactly like this: `Server=localhost;Database=construction_project;Uid=root;Pwd=myPassword;CharSet=utf8;` Did it work?

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work... :(